# Why is javascript array object undefined after logging array contents to the console?

Tags: javascript

Trying to access and compare the value of an object's property inside my LobbyQueue class. I've successfully added data to the array from server.js, and logged it. but when I try to use a method from LobbyQueue class to access & compare an object's property value form the array, I get `undefined` for the array index.

I've tried looping through the array's contents from inside the Queue class. this is where I'm getting undefined's

LobbyQueue.js:

```
class LobbyQueue {
  constructor() {
    this.players = [];
  }
  enqueue(player) {
    this.players.push(player);
  }
  dequeue() {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      return "Wait List is Empty";
    }
    return this.players.shift();
  }
  hasUser(username) {
    if (this.players.length == 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.players.length; ++i) {
        if (typeof this.players[i][username] === "undefined") {
          console.log("this.players[" + i + "][username] is undefined...");
          if (this.players[i][username] === username) {
            console.log("username comparison  entered...");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
module.exports = LobbyQueue;
```

server.js:

```
const queue = new LobbyQueue();
var gameRooms = [];

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("a user connected..." + "\n");

  socket.on("addPlayer", username => {
    if (queue.hasUser(username)) {
      console.log("user already in queue...");
    } else {
      console.log("New user joined: " + username);
      queue.enqueue({
        username: username,
        id: socket.id
      });
      socket.join("lobby");

      const players = queue.getAll();
      console.log("Players in queue: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(players));

      io.sockets.in("lobby").emit("players", players);
    }
  });
...
```

I expect `hasUser()`to prevent a duplicate connection being created. but its not returning `true` when the username already exists in the queue. it's as if the user doesn't exist when it loops over the array. but since the queue was logged to the console and the username and connection id are there, Im not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change condition to

```
typeof this.players[i]['username'] === "undefined"
```

Because you need access property name 'username'

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.players.length; ++i) {
        if (typeof this.players[i]['username'] === "undefined") {
          console.log("this.players[" + i + "][username] is undefined...");
          if (this.players[i]['username'] === username) {
            console.log("username comparison  entered...");
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hasPlayer(username) {
    return this.players.find(player => player['username'] == username) != null;
}
```

Comment: this prevents the same username from being duplicated. why is that? and why didn't my loop work as expected?

Comment: Because the function you wrote did not return true if the user exists, it only logs to the console. if you change this `console.log("username comparison entered...");` to `return true;` it should work.

Comment: Also `this.players[i][username]` will not work you should change it to `this.players[i]['username']`

Comment: the reason I originally logged "username comparison entered" was because the condition wasn't being entered because the array index was undefined